# Custom users not superusers from django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I started with Django Rest Framework official tutorial (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/) earlier today, 
and I have a question in the authentication and permissions section,

If I want to have custom users table, not the default superuser created by Django, is there any feature in DRF that help me with this requirement ??

and if there isn't, is it a good way to use the    `python manage.py createsuperuser`  to create a whole table of users that may contain 100 user ??

Im new to python, django, and DRF

so thanks for any help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Django includes a User model and you can create any number of users, either normal or superuser.

Comment: what I mean is that I need a customer model ,and the customer will technically be a user which can login , logout , and perform some of the APIs I’m developing, is it technically right  to create this customer using the user model , or its better to create a custom user model ?

Comment: It is not only technically right it is absolutely the correct thing to do.

Comment: You should read here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

and here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

This are basically two patterns that are proposed by django developers. If you will keep interfaces (inherit from one of the django abstract users models) drf - will have no problem to handle that.